How to Extract Running Balance in SQL Server
I want to extract the running balance in an account statement as the formula should be as below but the running_balance is calculating wrong, looking for your kind help guys.
the formula should be:
Running_balance = (Opening_balance + Credit_amount) - Debit_amount
The SQL query that I created is:
select ISNULL(bb.Credit_amount, 0) + ISNULL(bb.opening_balance, 0) -  ISNULL(bb.Debit_amount, 0) Balance
from transaction_tbl;

the result what I am getting:



Trn_date
Closing_Balance
opening_balance
Credit_amount
Debit_amount
Running_balance




01-Jan-23
343.00
0.00
10,343.00
0.0
10,343


01-Jan-23
343.00
0.00
0.00
10,000
-10,000



the result should be as follows:



Trn_date
Closing_Balance
opening_balance
Credit_amount
Debit_amount
Running_balance




01-Jan-23
343.00
0.00
10,343.00
0.0
10,343


01-Jan-23
343.00
0.00
0.00
10,000
343.00




Is there any column which orders the transactions?

use SUM with OVER clause

@TimBiegeleisen actually there is one column Trn_date to order the transactions

Both transaction dates appear identical.  You need a sequence column.

@IbrahimCheshti A transaction date usually includes a time. Is this the case in your DB and you just removed the time in your question?

Even if Trn_date contains a time, that does not necessarily guarantee uniqueness. You need something that defines an unambiguous order to the transactions. Also, your Opening_balance and Closing_Balance are the same for both records. Do these represent the opening/closing balance for the current day? The current accounting period (month)? The life of the account? Understanding that is critical to knowing how to calculate the running balance. As Squirrel mentioned, the SUM() OVER() window function is likely what you need, but you need to set partition-by to match your accounting period.

@TimBiegeleisen actually the Opening_balance and Closing_balance might be different and it represents the current date.

@JonasMetzler actually there is only date in the column not the time
